# How to print line/lines before regex match in powerShell?

Tags: powershell

Below is the auto-generated example.txt file:

```
    Application Name:       XYZSNWJ
    Secret Key:             NDRkNDJcvWDFW
    Application Name:       XYZSNWKkms
    Secret Key:             DFSmnbaDFAsdc
    Application Name:       HBDFJHXPI
    Application Name:       XHjacvJHasxb
```

And the output should be like below using **regex** or any other command:

```
    Application Name:       XYZSNWJ
    Secret Key:             NDRkNDJcvWDFW
    Application Name:       XYZSNWKkms
    Secret Key:             DFSmnbaDFAsdc
```

How to do it in **powerShell.**
The file is auto-generated, so there may be from 0 to n time blocks available in a file, like this:

```
    Application Name:       XYZSNWJ
    Secret Key:             NDRkNDJcvWDFW
    Application Name:       XYZSNWKkms
    Secret Key:             DFSmnbaDFAsdc
    Application Name:       HBDFJHXPI
    Application Name:       XHjacvJHasxb 
    Application Name:       XYZSNWJ
    Secret Key:             NDRkNDJcvWDFW
    Application Name:       XYZSNWKkms
    Secret Key:             DFSmnbaDFAsdc
    Application Name:       HBDFJHXPI
    Application Name:       XHjacvJHasxb 
    Application Name:       XYZSNWJ
    Secret Key:             NDRkNDJcvWDFW
    Application Name:       XYZSNWKkms
    Secret Key:             DFSmnbaDFAsdc
    Application Name:       HBDFJHXPI
    Application Name:       XHjacvJHasxb 
    Application Name:       XYZSNWJ
    Secret Key:             NDRkNDJcvWDFW
    Application Name:       XYZSNWKkms
    Secret Key:             DFSmnbaDFAsdc
    Application Name:       HBDFJHXPI
    Application Name:       XHjacvJHasxb 
    Application Name:       XYZSNWJ
    Secret Key:             NDRkNDJcvWDFW
    Application Name:       XYZSNWKkms
    Secret Key:             DFSmnbaDFAsdc
    Application Name:       HBDFJHXPI
    Application Name:       XHjacvJHasxb
```

then how it should be repeated till the end of file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following removes everything from the input starting with the first two consecutive lines that each start with `Application Name:`, possibly preceded by tabs and/or spaces, using the [`-replace` operator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40683667/45375).

```sh
@'
    Application Name:       XYZSNWJ
    Secret Key:             NDRkNDJcvWDFW
    Application Name:       XYZSNWKkms
    Secret Key:             DFSmnbaDFAsdc
    Application Name:       HBDFJHXPI
    Application Name:       XHjacvJHasxb 
'@ > example.txt

(Get-Content -Raw example.txt) -creplace
  '\r?\n[ \t]*Application Name:.+\r?\n[ \t]*Application Name:[\s\S]+$'
```